# How can I customize "My Work" pane format in Visual Studio Team Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfs-workitem

I'd like to remove "Code reviews" section at all to see more available work items.
Also, I want to change format of the records in "available work items" section:
Now it is shown as "ID - title" and I want to add there more columns (priority, original estimate etc.)
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to customize "My Work" page in Team Explorer, you need to work with your own VS addin. Use the [TeamExplorerPageIds.MyWork](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.controls.teamexplorerpageids.mywork(v=vs.110).aspx) to get MyWork page.

For further information on how to get it work, please check the following links for the  sample project:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Extending-Explorer-in-9dccd594

https://binary-stuff.com/list/visual+studio+plugin

Answer (score 0):

You cannot customize Team Explorer.